# ID for NFC devices in NFC P2P communication

Tags: nfc, nfc-p2p

I would like to know whether NFC P2P requires something like a MAC address that needs to be configured to be used for identification while creating a link layer connection or maybe even at transport layer connection.
I could see some details in specifications (ISO/IEC 18092) related to IDs being random values that are generated and maintained (per connection) for link layer connections.

I would be thankful if someone can please advice me on where can I find more details on the same or provide some light into how NFC devices are uniquely identified in P2P communications.

Answer (score 0):

NFC P2P does not require a MAC address or comparable mechanism to address a communication partner on the network. It is purely a one-to-one network and the communication partner is uniquely given by this association. A scenario where communication would only be possible with selected peers is not foreseen on the link level, the link is intended to work with any peer. Device identifications must be implemented in application protocols, when needed. Unique identification of a peer device on the link level would raise serious privacy concerns while there is no technical need.